# Help with a proof of Borsuk-Ulam theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Here's the question.

> Let $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $[0, 1]$ with $f(0) = f(1)$. Prove that there exists a point $c \in [0,1/2]$ such that $f(c) = f(c + 1/2).$ Deduce that there are always a pair of antipodal points on the Earth’s equator that
>   have the same temperature.

This is what I've come up with so far:

Since $f(0) = f(1)$ there exists an $x^*$ s.t. either
$$
f(x) \geq f(x^*) \; \forall x \in [x^*,1]
$$
or
$$
f(x) \leq f(x^*) \; \forall x \in [x^*,1].
$$
(I don't know if there's a name for this theorem but it feels fairly intuitive). Now by IVT there exists $x_1 \in [x^*, 1]$ s.t. $f(x_1) = c$ and there exists $x_2 \in [0, x^*]$ s.t. $f(x_2) = c$ as well. I don't know how to show that we can pick $c$ s.t. $x_1 = x_2 + 1/2$.

As for the second part I assume we just map the equator on the line $[0,1]$, define two antipodal points $(c_1, c_2)$ s.t. $c_1 \in [0,1/2]$ and $c_2 \in [1/2,1]$ and $c_1 = c_2 + 1/2$. Letting $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be the temperature at point $x$. By the previous theorem we know there exists $(c_1, c_2)$ s.t. $f(x) = c_1 = c_2$ so two antipodal points have the same temperature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $g(x)=f(x)-f(x+1/2)$ defined on $[0,1/2]$, $g(0)$ and $g(1/2)$ have opposite signs, there exits $c$ with $g(c)=0$.

For the second question, take a circle in the equator, it is the quotient of $[0,1]$ let $p$ the quotient map, where $0$ and $1$ are identified, if $T$ is the temperature, defined $\bar T:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $\bar T(x)=T(p(x))$ and apply the previous result.

Comment: Thx, should of just gone with the usual route of defining new functions and looking for zeroes.